# Block a caller/contact from user's contact list in iOS

Tags: ios

Presently I'm developing an iOS app to block unwanted contact/caller from user's contact list.
In this app user will be shown a list of contact from his phone book and user can mark block/unblock a contact/caller,Now if a contact/caller mark as blocked the app should block the call(it might ring once and then be disconnected automatically).

can any one suggest me how it is possible? please.
Reference: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/call-bliss-silence-calls-text/id575698521?mt=8

Thank you so much.

Comment: why do you develop such thing which the iOS offers anyway to the users as default?

Comment: I am not willing to spend the $15 to confirm, but I suspect that the app has you set up a group in the DND configuration and then this app puts the people you haven't blocked into that group and allows you to easily add/remove people from the list, managing the group for you behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

iPhones/iOS already have a block contact/caller option

Comment: thank you ,but i have to do via app please check reference app.